# How to merge two vector pairs of different sizes

Tags: c++, vector, std-pair

I have two vectors that I want merged into one. Both are embedded pair vectors (to be able to hold 3 int values in one pair) and their sizes are different from eachother.

Code for the two pair vectors and the merged Vector is:

```
vector < pair<int, pair<int,int> > > parentVect;
vector < pair<int, pair<int,int> > > childVect;
vector < pair<int, pair<int,int> > > mergedVect;
```

where sizeOfFinalVect is equal to the size of both the parentVect + childVect.

parentVect = {( 0 3 9 ), ( 1 3 9 ), ( 2 2 15 )}
 childVect = {( 0 1 9 )}

When I run:

```
 for(int i=0; i<mergedVect.size();i++){
    mergedVect.push_back(make_pair(parentVect[i].second.second, make_pair(parentVect[i].second.first, parentVect[i].first)));
}
```

(I know that forloop is not "merging" the two, I wanted to check if it was at least adding in the parentVect pairs to mergedVect)

my output is:

mergedVect = {( 0 0 0 ), ( 0 0 0 ), ( 0 0 0 )}

The vectors are sorted by the last integer in the pair so my desired output is:

mergedVect = {( 0 3 9 ), ( 1 3 9 ), ( 0 1 9 ), (2 2 15)}

Any help on this is greatly appreciated!

EDIT:

Using merge:

```
merge(parentVect.begin(), parentVect.end(), childVect.begin(), childVect.end(), std::back_inserter(mergedVect));
```

my output is 
mergedVect = {( 0 1 9 ), ( 0 3 9 ), ( 1 3 9 ), ( 2 2 15 )}

Comment: [std::inplace_merge](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/inplace_merge)

Comment: `i<mergedVect.size()` is not a good loop control condition, since you are increasing both of those values by 1 with every iteration of your loop.

Comment: Not sure how that helps? @PaulMcKenzie

Comment: Ok, I've changed it to 'i<sizeOfFinalVect' @DrewDormann

Comment: You are trying to merge two sorted sequences, correct?  Then the algorithm is `inplace_merge` or [std::merge](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/merge)

Comment: I've edited the post to include what I get when I use std::merge @PaulMcKenzie

Comment: You didn't post a [mcve].  We have no idea where your real program breaks down.  I also posted an answer, showing that `merge` works correctly, given the criteria you are describing.

Comment: You sized the `mergedVect` **before** you started to push_back items in it.  That's probably why you see those extraneous zero items in the front of `mergedVect`.  Look at the answer I posted -- the `mergedVect` starts out as empty.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to merge two sorted sequences into one sequence, the algorithm function you should be taking advantage of is [std::merge](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/merge).

Here is an example, using your data:

```
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

typedef std::pair<int, int> PairInt;
typedef std::pair<int, PairInt> PairPairInt;
typedef std::vector<PairPairInt> PairVect;

// lambda that compares the pairs on the last value in the pair sequence
auto comparer = [](const PairPairInt& p1, const PairPairInt& p2) {return p1.second.second < p2.second.second; };

int main()
{
    PairVect parentVect = { { 0,{ 3, 9 } },{ 1,{ 3, 9 } },{ 2,{ 2, 15 } } };
    PairVect childVect = { { 0,{ 1, 9 } } };
    PairVect mergedVect;

    // First, sort the sequences based on the criteria that the
    // last number in the pairs is sorted in ascending order
    std::sort(parentVect.begin(), parentVect.end(), comparer);
    std::sort(childVect.begin(), childVect.end(), comparer);

    // Now merge the two sequences above, using the same sorting criteria
    std::merge(parentVect.begin(), parentVect.end(), 
               childVect.begin(), childVect.end(), 
               std::back_inserter(mergedVect), comparer);

    for (auto& p : mergedVect)
        std::cout << "{" << p.first << " " << p.second.first << " " << p.second.second << "}\n";
}
```

Output:

```
{0 3 9}
{1 3 9}
{0 1 9}
{2 2 15}
```

[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/27f34b639f0cdf1c)

Note the usage of `std::sort`, as `std::merge` requires sorted ranges.

Comment: Read my comments in the main section.  You more than likely started `mergedVect` with items -- it did not start out empty as the code above shows.  More to the point `vector < pair<int, pair<int,int> > > mergedVect(sizeOfFinalVect);` -- That line adds `sizeOfFinalVect` pairs to your vector.  If you want proof, call `mergedVect.size()` right after that line of code.

Comment: Ok I've fixed those mistakes. I no longer get the extra 4 pairs of 0. However, when it merges childVect is still merged out of place. I took a look at your code but the pairs to both parentVect and childVect are being read in so I can't just assign them the way you did. Not sure how to work around that

Comment: @Pvelez_3 -- Take what I posted and make it a function that just does the sorting and merging.  Separation  of concerns.  Then work on the inputting of the data separately, as it has nothing to do with accomplishing the goal of merging two sorted sequences.

Comment: what do the [ ] do in the line `auto comparer = [](const PairPairInt& p1, const PairPairInt& p2) {return p1.second.second < p2.second.second; };`

Comment: That is the lambda capture syntax.  This is better explained in any tutorial focused on C++ 11.